# scheduling a task not working in Python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, feedparser

i'm trying to schedule a task every 5 seconds, here what i did:

```
conn = connect('mydatabase.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RSSEntries (entry_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title , url , date );')


def checkLink(linko):
    c.execute("SELECT entry_id FROM RSSEntries WHERE url = ?", (linko,))
    datas=c.fetchall()

    if len(datas)==0:
    return True

    else:
    return False



def storeData():
    data = feedparser.parse("http://www...")
    for i in range(len(data['entries'])):

    if checkLink(data.entries[i].link) is True:
        print "doesn't exist"
        c.execute("insert into RSSEntries VALUES\
          (NULL,'%s', '%s', '%s')" % (data.entries[i].title,data.entries[i].link, data.feed.updated))

    else:
        print "exist"


schedule.every(5).seconds.do(storeData)
conn.commit()
```

but the `storeData` method is not reachable..
if i run `storeData()` instead of `schedule.every(5).seconds.do(storeData)` the code work perfectly, what i'm doing wrong

any suggesting or other ways to do this task are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the scheduler loop at the end of your script:

```
while True:
   schedule.run_pending()
   time.sleep(1)
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule

Comment: it worked Thank you, can you please explain why `schedule.every(5).seconds.do(storeData)` didn't work

Comment: by `schedule.every(5).seconds.do(storeData)` you just a set the parameters for scheduler object. Without calling scheduler method `run_pending()`  the clock is not started